# Can we write $f(\emptyset) = \{y\in Y|\exists x\in X(y=f(x))\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$.
$f(X):=\{y\in Y|\exists x\in X(y=f(x))\}$.

I think we can write $f(X):=\{y\in Y|\exists x\in X(y=f(x))\}$ if and only if $X\neq\emptyset.$

Let $X\neq\emptyset$ and $\Gamma\subset X\times Y$ be a graph of $f:X\to Y$.
Let $x\in X$.
Then there is a unique element $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in\Gamma$.
We write this $y$ as $f(x)$.

Let $\Gamma\subset\emptyset\times Y=\emptyset$ be the graph of $f:\emptyset\to Y$.
Then, there is no $y$ such that $(x,y)\in\Gamma$.
So, I think we cannot write $f(x)$ in this case.
So, I think we cannot write $f(\emptyset) = \{y\in Y|\exists x\in X(y=f(x))\}$.
Instead, I think we can write $f(\emptyset) = \{y\in Y|\exists x\in X((x,y)\in\Gamma)\}$.

Can we write $f(\emptyset) = \{y\in Y|\exists x\in X(y=f(x))\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with writing
$$
f\left(\varnothing\right) = \{ y \in Y \mid \exists x \in \varnothing,~ f(x)=y\} \label{1} \tag{1}
$$
because the condition $\exists x \in \varnothing$ is always false. Hence, the condition for $y$ to be in $f(\varnothing)$ is never satisfied and the equality \eqref{1} is just $f(\varnothing) = \varnothing$, which is obviously true.

Comment: dear Didier, +1, but your second paragraph is not quite right; there *is* a function $f:\varnothing\to Y$ for *any* set $Y$, and indeed a unique such: the [empty function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#empty_function), which has $\varnothing$ as its graph. (one can check all the conditions of being a function $\varnothing\to Y$ are satisfied.) what is true is that there does not exist any function $Y\to\varnothing$ if $Y$ is non-empty

Comment: You are right, I did not really thought about that. Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure, yes it's a bit strange! :) [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities) is a nice thread that has a lot of similar examples of "interesting vacuity", if you're interested

Comment: Didier, Thank you very much for your answer.